# install driver using c++

Tags: c++, dll, driver

I'm trying to install driver behind the user:

I've create DLL which call SetupCopyOEMInf using c++ then i call it from VB application:

C++ code:

```
PBOOL bRebootRequired = false;
PCTSTR szInfFileName = (PCTSTR) "c:\\temp\\ttt\\Driver\\slabvcp.inf";

if(!SetupCopyOEMInf(szInfFileName,NULL, SPOST_PATH, SP_COPY_REPLACEONLY, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)){;
DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;

FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,0, NULL );

MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
```

}

And when i call this function i receiving error "The system cannot find the file specified."

But the path to my file is correct.

Comment: "I'm trying to install driver behind the user" - I don't like the sound of this...

Comment: my english is not perfect. I just try to install driver (com to usb driver) without user because they don't know how to do it. This is soft for working with external device.

Comment: There is a bug here btw: lpDisplayBuf will be undefined when an error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PCTSTR szInfFileName = (PCTSTR) "c:\\temp\\ttt\\Driver\\slabvcp.inf";
```

A cast is *not* going to work, it will turn your 8-bit character string into Chinese.  Fix:

```
PCTSTR szInfFileName = _T("c:\\temp\\ttt\\Driver\\slabvcp.inf");
```